# density function estimation in r

Tags: r, nonparametric-density

I firstly generate data from a bivariate normal distribution. Here comes the code.

```r
n <- 10000
set.seed(123) #for reproducible results
dat <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=n, 
               mu=c(0, 0), 
               Sigma= matrix(c(2, 0.5, 0.5, 2), 
               byrow=T, ncol=2)
)
```

Now what I want to do is ignore that I know the data if from normal. I would like to approximate the density function from the data I sampled, and compare the estimated model and the true one. I try to search the literature but I did not see any code relevant to this.Do anyone know how to do this in R?Which kind of measure can I use to approximate the density function?

---

The main question is I would like to approximate the density function from the data I sampled before(without knowing that it is normal).I am wondering is there any package or measures that I can do to approximate?Is that solvable?
I also read some literature related to Neural Density Estimation which is use neural network to do the density estimation.I am wondering is that a suitable way to do so?

---

I tried to use kernel density estimation and I can draw the density function of the data.But the point is I want to determine what exactly is the density function.

[image]

Comment: How will you conduct MLE (presumably, maximum likelihood estimation) without making a distributional assumption?  Requests for code are not on topic here, but perhaps there is a statistical question you need resolved anyway.  Could you provide more details or clarifications?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to estimate the mean and covariance matrix via maximum likelihood, plug those estimates into a normal distribution, and see how that compares to some kind of software-graphed density estimate?

Comment: hii,I would like to approximate the distribution then use this assumption to do MLE

Comment: @AuroraJoy What do you mean by that if you don’t mean what I wrote in my earlier comment?

Comment: @Dave Hi,I am sorry for the ambiguousness,I would like to estimate the  mean and covariance matrix via maximum likelihood(based on the distributional assumption I got from approximation),my main question is to approximate the density function of the sampled data.And then compare the estimate to the real one.

Comment: How would you get a distribution assumption from a density plot? // The R function MASS::kde2d might help.

Comment: @Dave Thank you so much!

Comment: A sample has no density function.  Any finite sample is consistent with infinitely many density functions.  The only way to make progress towards identifying a *unique* density consistent with the sample is to postulate a family of densities and select a member of that family that best fits the data.